# Как подменить текст в запросе sql во время поиска?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется две таблицы.

Первая:

```
Name_short | Value
АО "СЗП"      | 10
```

Вторая:

```
Name_full
Акционерное общество "Саранский завод Пупкина"
```

Говорю сразу - Был бы id можно было сделать джоин по нему, но его нет.

Входные данные для поиска:
АО "Саранский завод Пупкина"

Мы ничего не найдем, не по первой, не по второй таблице.

Возможно ли, например, во время поиска подменять слова на слова из списка, например:

Spisok=([ао; акционерное общество],[зао;закрытое акционерное общество],[ооо;общество с ограниченной ответственностью]);

1. Ищем:

АО "Саранский завод Пупкина"

2. Не находим и поменяем во время поиска АО на полное наименование
3. Профит

Дело в том, что отрубать начало нельзя и искать чисто по наименованию без правовой формы так как, будут выдаваться невалидные названия типа ЗАО или ОА из-за вхождения АО в эти слов.

В sql со списками, массивами и переменными не знаком, от сюда и перебрать данные у меня не получается. Функцию Replace делать умею, но получается конструкция типо запроса в запросе, да еще и 'ао', как буквы в слове могут встречаться. Есть идеи?

Comment: На мой взгляд, нужно для поиска приводить данные к единой форме. Например, отдельно сокращённую правовую форму и отдельно название. Из `name_full` можно вычленить отдельно форму с помощю регулярки или `case when name_full like "Акционерное общество%" then "АО"` и отдельно название регуляркой по кавычкам вычленять

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант решения вашей проблемы средствами SQL в случае если количество замен не слишком большое можно использовать CASE:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON CASE WHEN t1.Name_short = 'АО'  THEN REPLACE(t1.Name_short, 'АО', 'акционерное общество')
                     WHEN t1.Name_short = 'ЗАО' THEN REPLACE(t1.Name_short, 'ЗАО', 'закрытое акционерное общество')
                 ELSE t1.Name_short
                 END = t2.Name_full
```

В случае если таких замен много, то лучше сделать отдельную таблицу, состоящую из двух столбцов **short_name** и **full_name** и делать join через эту таблицу.