# Как вырезать/вычленить значение до определённого символа в sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Имеется таблица типа:

```
Наименование
АО "Завод Пупкин "Росмоском"
АО "Предприятие Щукина "Портик" филиал"
ЗАО НИИ имени Ломоносова "Горсвет"
```

Нужно получить:

```
Наименование 
"Росмоском"
"Портик"
"Горсвет"
```

С substring знаком, но умею резать лишь до первой или последней ковычки.

Как указать номер знака ("), чтобы возможно было получать адекватные ответы и можно ли создать конструкцию типа if, else if, else if, else для того, чтобы прописать все условия в запрос?
Есть ли другие варианты решения данной проблемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соглашусь с @zhukov_roman, что поменяв схему, можно было бы решить много проблем. Памятуя ваш [предыдущий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553443/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-sql-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) вопрос, логичным было бы выделить таблицу для хранения организационных форм, для предприятий (полное и сокращённое имя) и атрибутов предприятий. Тем не менее, отвечая на вопрос в поставленной форме можно попробовать рекурсивно отсекать всё, что вне самых внешних кавычек, чтобы добраться до содержимого внутренних. (Или использовать хитрую регулярку, решающую проблему в лоб но я сходу не придумал). На Oracle это было бы что-то вроде

```
with names(name) as
(select full_name name from fn
 union all
 select trim('"' from regexp_substr(name, '".*"'))
   from names
  where name is not null)
select name    
 from names
 where instr(name, '"') = 0
```

В PostgreSQL, полагаю, для регулярных выражений можно использовать `substring`, вместо `instr` — `position`

Примеры названий, которые вы привели, демонстрируют проблему, с которой придётся столкнуться - кавычки могут быть не парными из-за опечаток, могут быть разные кавычки и т.п. С этим всем придётся разбираться отдельно.

Comment: Столбец уже есть, в нем все сокращения, но правовых форм много, как и правил сокращения их, от сюда эти извращения. Ваш вариант попробую.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли другие варианты решения данной проблемы?

Да, есть. Идеальным решением было было введение колонки "Сокращенное наименование", которое заполняется вручную. Это быстрее, точнее и снимает последующие проблемы поддержки кода "автоматического" вычленения краткого имени.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  CASE  
    WHEN 'АО "Завод Пупкин "Росмоском"' REGEXP '.*".*".*"$' 
    THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('АО "Завод Пупкин Росмоском"','"',3),'"',-1)
  END AS ORG_NAME
```

И таких кейсов на все варианты кавычек